# Best way to handle buttons with an action (but not form action)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, view, hyperlink

In my code I use the aristo design buttons, I insert them like:

```
    %button.aristo-default
      &laquo My button text
```

This works very inconvenient cause sometimes I need a link on the button and that is not possible with this code without using query on click events { :onclick => '' )

What would be a good way to implement a link in rails and make it look like a button, just plain CSS hacking or are there some other good methods?

UPDATE:
Since I'm only looking to make a link look like a button, I think I better look for a solution to do so in CSS. Using the button element implies a form post wich I don't care about, just getting my link "buttoned"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to do, suggest using the `button_to` helper. This helps implement a POST to a specified URL (or you can specify other HTTP verbs if those are appropriate). See [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) for Rails documentation on `button_to`

Alternatively, if you want a form tag helper, try `button_tag` - you can read more about this [here.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-button_tag)

If you are just looking to take a link and style it as a button (keeping in mind that the general philosophy is that buttons are meant for those links/actions that result in something changing), you could just give your `<a>` element a class of `button` and style that using CSS.

Comment: After rethinking my question, what Im trying todo is to have links that looks like buttons using the aristo theme to no avail. I think that adding using the button tag is wrong since that implies a form post, and I'm aiming just to style my links like buttons, thx

Comment: You might find this tutorial useful then: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-gradient-buttons